# PL/SQL Add record Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have two tables, Book and Book Copy. I am trying to add a record to book and then a corresponding record into book copy.
So far I have this Procedure;

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_BOOK (B_ISBN IN VARCHAR2,
B_TITLE IN VARCHAR2, B_SUMMARY IN VARCHAR2, B_AUTHOR IN VARCHAR2,
B_DATE_PUBLISHED IN DATE, B_PAGE_COUNT IN INT)
AS
BEGIN
  IF B_ISBN IS NULL
   THEN
      RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO BOOKS (ISBN,TITLE,SUMMARY,AUTHOR,DATE_PUBLISHED, PAGE_COUNT)
  VALUES (B_ISBN, B_TITLE, B_SUMMARY, B_AUTHOR, B_DATE_PUBLISHED, B_PAGE_COUNT);    
END ADD_BOOK;
```

I have then been trying to call the procedure;

```
BEGIN
ADD_BOOK(1-56592-335-9,'Oracle PL/SQL Programming,Reference for PL/SQL developers including examples and best practice recommendations,Fuerenstein','Steven with Bill Pribyl',01-SEP-1997,987);
END;
/
```

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? Please note that `Varchar2` and `Date` should be in quotes while the procedure is being called. Also the number of parameters is also wrong. Should be 6.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the values in the wrong way.

```
BEGIN
  ADD_BOOK(
     '1-56592-335-9', --<< quotes were missing
     'Oracle PL/SQL Programming,Reference for PL/SQL developers including examples and best practice recommendations,Fuerenstein',
     'Steven with Bill Pribyl',
     DATE '1997-09-01', <<-- use a proper date literal
     987);
END;
/
```

I prefer ANSI date literals like `DATE '1997-09-01'`, if you want to write your date literals in a different format, you have to use `to_date()`, e.g.: `to_date('01-SEP-1997', 'dd-mon-yyyy')`. This is subject to the NLS language that is currently defined for your session (it would fail if the client's language is e.g. Italian)

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your stored proc to include the insert stmt for BOOKCOPY after inserting to BOOK table

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_BOOK (B_ISBN IN VARCHAR2, B_TITLE IN VARCHAR2, 
B_SUMMARY IN VARCHAR2, B_AUTHOR IN VARCHAR2, 
B_DATE_PUBLISHED IN DATE, B_PAGE_COUNT IN INT) 
AS BEGIN 
IF B_ISBN IS NULL THEN RAISE VALUE_ERROR; END IF;

INSERT INTO BOOK(ISBN,TITLE,SUMMARY,AUTHOR,DATE_PUBLISHED, PAGE_COUNT) 
VALUES (B_ISBN, B_TITLE, B_SUMMARY, B_AUTHOR, B_DATE_PUBLISHED, B_PAGE_COUNT);

--Assuming the table structure for BOOK and BOOKCOPY are same
INSERT INTO BOOKCOPY (ISBN,TITLE,SUMMARY,AUTHOR,DATE_PUBLISHED, PAGE_COUNT) 
VALUES (B_ISBN, B_TITLE, B_SUMMARY, B_AUTHOR, B_DATE_PUBLISHED, B_PAGE_COUNT);

END ADD_BOOK;
```